# How to pass button value to another component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I want to pass table cell data(URL) to another IFrame component.

The web app is used to preview CSV URL data, Once the URL clicked I want to show the web in the IFrame.

[image]

```
<table className="table table-responsive overflow-x">
  <tbody>
    {items.map((d, x) => (
      <tr key={d.x}>
        <td scope="row">{x + 1}</td>
        <td id="urlcol">
          <button className="btn" onClick={(e) => this.onClick(e)}>
            {d.Link_Address}{" "}
          </button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    ))}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Iframe Component

[image]

How can I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: But are you rendering the BooksIframe in the table cell component. I don't see that

Comment: @tushar-shahi  I updated the question with another component.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the double qoutes " " from:

```
<Iframe url="{props.url}" />
```

Should be like this:

```
<Iframe url={props.url} />
```

in general if you want to pass something from Parent component to child component, will be like this:

Parent component:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Child from './Child.js';

export default function Parent(){
  //you can put anything in inside useEffect, not only an array
  const [items, setItems] = useState(['item1','item2','item3']);
  const [currentItem, setCurrentItem] = useState('item1');
  
  const changeCurrentItem = (item)=> {
     setCurrentItem(item);
 }

 return (<div>

        {items.map((item, key)=> {return <button key={key} onClick={()=> changeCurrentItem(item)} > {item} </button>})}

        <div className='child-component-container'>
        <Child item={currentItem} />
        </div>

        </div>)
 }
```

Child component:

```
import React from 'react';


export default function Child(props){
 
 return (<div>

<p> item from Parent component: {props.item} </p>

</div>);

 }
```

Comment: I change it. But is not working.

Comment: Please put both components to see.

Comment: @A97 I edited my answer and added an example how to pass props from parent to child components. Read it and try to do the same with your application, and then tell me what will happen.

Comment: Thank you so much!. I updated the question with another component.